# Uncaught ReferenceError: caiet is not defined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate some fields and checkboxes and ultimately count the number of checked checkboxes.

My code currently shows an alert if 2 values are not the same and the user needs to fill a formula with checkboxes and sum them, but I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: caiet is not defined   
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (stoc_placi.php?id_order=384&id_sablon=80:731)  
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)  
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

#### My code

```js
$('[name^="caiet_tabel"]').change(function ()
{
    if ($(this).closest('tr').find('td:not(".all") input:checked').length == 4) {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.all').prop('checked', true);
        sumAll(this);
    }
    let index = $(this).parent().index();
    sumRow(this, index);
});

$('.all').click(function ()
{
    sumAll(this);
})

function sumRow(el, index)
{
    sumGrup(el);
    let caiet = $(el).closest('tbody');
    let count = caiet.find('tr').find(' > td:eq(' + (index - 1) + ') 
    input: checked ').length;
    caiet.find('.total td:eq(' + (index - 1) + ')').text(count);
}

function sumGrup(el)
{
    let tot =
        $(el).closest('.bife_caiet').find('[name^="caiet_tabel"]:checked').length;
    $(el).closest('.bife_caiet').siblings('.nr_caiet').find('.showcaiet').text(tot);
}

function sumAll(el)
{
    let caiet = $(el).closest('tbody');
    sumGrup(el)
    caiet.find('.total td').each(function (index, v)
    {
        let count = caiet.find('tr').find(' > td:eq(' + (index - 1) + ') 
          input: checked ').length;
          caiet.find('.total td:eq(' + (index - 1) + ')').text(count);
    })
}

$('.calculeaza').click(function ()
{
    var c1 = parseInt($('.c1').val());
    var c2 = parseInt($('.c2').val());
    var c3 = parseInt($('.c3').val());
    let sum = 0;
    caiet.find('.total td').each(function (index, v)
    {
        sum += caiet.find('tr').find(' > td:eq(' + (index - 1) + ') input: checked ').length;
    })

    if (c1 + c2 + c3 != parseInt($('#placi_bugetate').val())) {
        alert('Suma paginilor declarate la caiete difera de numarul de pagini 
              solicitat de client ');

          } else if (sum != parseInt($('#placi_bugetate').val())) {
        alert('Suma bifelor selectate este diferita de numar-ul paginilor 
              propuse ');
          } else {
        alert('datele sunt corecte');
    }
})

$('.stoc-form').submit(function (e)
{

    if ($('#placi-ofertate').val() != $('#placi_bugetate').val()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // $("#myModal").modal('show');
        $('[data-target="#myModal"]').trigger('click');
    }
})

var modalConfirm = function (callback)
{

    $("#btn-confirm").on("click", function ()
    {
        $("#mi-modal").modal('show');
    });

    $("#modal-btn-si").on("click", function ()
    {
        callback(true);
        $("#mi-modal").modal('hide');
    });

    $("#modal-btn-no").on("click", function ()
    {
        callback(false);
        $("#mi-modal").modal('hide');
    });
};

modalConfirm(function (confirm)
{
    if (confirm) {
        //Acciones si el usuario confirma
        $("#result").html("A apasat DA");
        $('.post-abs').click();
    } else {
        //Acciones si el usuario no confirma
        $("#result").html("A apasat NU");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the `caiet` variable outside of the function.

Declare `caiet` outside of the functions to access it globally

```
let caiet;
```

Then remove all this code inside of the functions.

```
let caiet = $(el).closest('tbody');
```

Then initialize the `caiet` inside of this:

```
let caiet;
$('[name^="caiet_tabel"]').change(function () {

    caiet = $(this).closest('tbody');
    if ($(this).closest('tr').find('td:not(".all") input:checked').length == 4) {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.all').prop('checked', true);
        sumAll(this);
    }
    let index = $(this).parent().index();
    sumRow(this, index);
});
$('.all').click(function () {
    caiet = $(this).closest('tbody');
    sumAll(this);
})
```

Comment: i got now  el is not defined

Comment: @CristinelToma I edited again. Did you try this yet?

Comment: Yes i tried already and i got now : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`

Comment: @CristinelToma I believe this is happening when the click event happen from `$('.calculeaza')` and inside of this function you are using `caiet` which is does not exist. Can I see how you implement my solution?

Comment: @CristinelToma I updated my answer. Please remove all the `let caiet = $(el).closest('tbody');`  inside of `sumAll()`

Comment: Neah, i got this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined` don`t worry thanks very much and i hope have a nice day maybe i will find another solution...